# dynamically retrieve sql and show it in a web page

Tags: php, sql

This is a basic PHP SQL question but I have been struggling with it for the last 2 days.

So I have page1 and page2. Page 1 contains a table with data from sql and on each row there is a button. when the user clicks the button specific to that row it will connect to page 2 which just says thank you for choosing the specific product. How do I pass the value to the second page when the user clicks the button?This is my code.

```
//page 1 
<form action="page2.php" method="GET"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Product" value="'.$row['Product'].'"/>
</form>
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
$conn=connect();
$sql = "SELECT * from Stock;";
$handle = $conn->prepare($sql);
$handle->execute();
$conn = null;
$res = $handle->fetchAll();  

echo '<table border="5" align="center">';
echo "<tr><th>Product</th><th>Price</th></td>";
foreach($res as $row){
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['Product'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Price'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo "<button>Choose me</button>";
echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
//page 2 
echo "Thank you for choosing " .$_GET["Product"]."!";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Page 2 looks fine, just make the buttons on page 1 links to page2 with the get param product with the value of that rows product.

Comment: Didn't I answer this same question earlier today?

Comment: <form> should have method POST.  A "name" in an input will be passed as part of the form ($_POST['Name']).

Comment: My answer to the deleted question shows how to make a separate form for each row of the table. I'm not going to do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is to place your form inside the `foreach` loop like that:

```
foreach($res as $row){

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['Product'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Price'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo '<form action="page2.php" method="GET"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="Product" value="'.$row['Product'].'"/>';
    echo "<button>Choose me</button>";
    echo '</form>';
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Another way is just use hyperlink in your `foreach` loop instead of button and style it as a button if you want:

```
foreach($res as $row){

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['Product'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Price'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<a href='page2.php?Product=" .$row['Product']. "'>Choose me</a>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a link instead of a button, and send Product ID through GET

```
$mysql_row = array(
    'ProductID'    => 1, 
    'ProductName'  => 'PS4', 
    'ProductPrice' => 499.00);

echo '<a href="show_product.php?Product='.$row['ProductID'].'">Choose me</a>';
```

Page 2 - Get ProductID, find it on Database and retrieve Product

```
$ProductID = 0;
if(isset($_GET["Product"]) && is_numeric($_GET["Product"])) {
    $ProductID = intval($_GET["Product"]);
}

if( $ProductID ) {
    // Find product by
    $row_mysql = find_product($_GET["Product"]);

    echo "Thank you for choosing " .$row["Product"]."!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
$conn=connect();
$sql = "SELECT * from Stock;";
$handle = $conn->prepare($sql);
$handle->execute();
$conn = null;
$res = $handle->fetchAll();

echo '<table border="5" align="center">';
echo "<tr><th>Product</th><th>Price</th></td>";
echo  '<form action="page2.php" method="POST"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Product" value="'.$row['Product'].'"/>
';
foreach($res as $row){
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['Product'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Price'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<button value='someValue'>Choose me</button>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo '<form>';
echo "</table>";
//page 2
echo "Thank you for choosing " .$_GET["Product"]."!";
```

insert the required value in the button instead of this dummy value value='someValue'

Comment: This is not exactly correct because the `$row['Product']` would be undefined  inside `<input type="hidden" name="Product" value="'.$row['Product'].'"/>`. You have to use form inside the foreach loop like in my answer

Comment: I just gave him the main idea so he can fix or add whatever he wants